# Best way to Refresh Web Page in the Background?

Tags: library, javascript

I feel like this is a common problem, yet I'm finding it difficult to find a good answer online. I currently have a flask application that's in connected to a database. As of now, the flask app returns an updated rendered html page every time the user hits refresh, however I want the user's page to be updated automatically in real time. For example, in instagram you don't have to refresh your page to see a new post, it just comes through when someone posted. Or when you chat with someone on Whatsapp, you don't have to refresh in order to see the other person's message. I want to know the best software (probably some js library) to constantly refresh the page in the background.

Comment: Have a look at WebSockets for a constant communication channel between client and server.

Comment: So I already have a flask restful-api set up, so I would like to keep that code. From what I've seen, a websocket backend needs socket.io javascript stuff right? Is there a way to instead make websocket connections with the flask backend that I already have?